# Make linux library visible for QT-program

Tags: linux, qt

I must run the QT-program from source code. But when I start it in QT-creator there is the exception 'cannot find -lpcap'. I have found this library in linux packages:
[image]

The dependencies to this library in .pro-file:

```
    unix {
LIBS += lpcap
}
```

How can I share the linux library to make it visible for QT-program? I must not change the source code, only make visible (share) the library

Comment: install dev(developers)  package: `libpcap-dev`

Comment: But if it is installed can we share it? To install is hard because the workplace has no internet and I must download it by hand... I read about static and dynamic libraries, may be some linking?

Comment: You can link statically if your library is, but the libraries provided by debian are dynamic link. also your question does not say that, read [ask] and improve your question, I also recommend reading about the various forms of packaging that exist in linux.